# Twitter. Getting old tweets in home_timeline

Tags: search, twitter

Anybody help me please... How can i access to the tweets in the home_timeline by date? not by id, but by date?

Comment: They're called tweets, not twits

Comment: Maybe Vesna is trying to access the users and not the posts?

Comment: They'd still be tweeps, not twits. And no he/she doesn't, as he/she said `home_timeline` which is a tweet endpoint.

Comment: i talk about access to the posts. I could get user_timeline with parameter max_id, and i get array of the tweets,  id of which is smaller than  this max_id. May be exist any way to get home_timeline until some date?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's ID algorithm is based on Snowflake, of which the first 41 bits are the timestamp. You should be able to reverse the Snowflake algorithm and find a few IDs to use as search criteria.

https://github.com/twitter/snowflake

Do note that Twitter simply doesn't offer you old `home_timeline` responses. You can't go back a year, and probably not even more than a few days.

Comment: mm...for example, i have date = 2012-08-05 23:35. And i want to find tweets, which were published until this date. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, get an ID for that date and then specify that as the max ID. However, Twitter may no longer have information about that date as it's a long time ago.